# ggplot: Desaturate/Make gray bars based on column value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to desaturate (or make gray) certain bars in a bar chart. I figured out how to make certain bars more transparent than others based on a column value using `alpha=column_name` in `geom_bar`. But I would like to make them gray not transparent. Is there a way to do it natively in ggplot?

Below is the code to make certain columns transparent based on column S. Is there a way to desaturate/make gray specific bars based on column value?

**Edited** code to include data.

```
data_t<-as.data.frame(Titanic)

     join_table<- data_t %>% group_by(X=Class) %>% summarise(Y=sum(Freq)) %>% 
mutate(S=ifelse(Y-mean(Y)>0,"a","b")) %>% select(X,  S); join_table

     data_t %>% group_by(X=Class, groups=Sex) %>% summarise(Y=sum(Freq)) %>%
       inner_join(join_table, by=c("X"))  %>%
       ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y)) + theme_minimal() +
       geom_bar(aes(fill=groups, alpha=S), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have more chances to have an answer if you `dput(your_final_data)`: in one hand, generally it's not a good idea to download files given by strangers (we are all strangers here), in the other hand your issues are on the plotting part, so the data manipulation is maybe useless.

Comment: Thank you. That was a valuable comment. I edited code to include data

Comment: So, in your example the first four bars should remain the same (red, turquoise) and then the other four should be grey?

Comment: Yep. That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the data plotted each time and adjust the `fill` colour accordingly. The following should work:

```
library(tidyverse)
data_t <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

join_table <- data_t %>% 
               group_by(X = Class) %>% 
               summarise(Y = sum(Freq)) %>% 
               mutate(S = ifelse(Y - mean(Y) > 0, "a", "b")) %>% 
               select(X, S)

data_t %>% 
  group_by(X = Class, groups = Sex) %>% 
  summarise(Y = sum(Freq)) %>%
  inner_join(join_table, by = c("X"))  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y)) + 
    theme_minimal() +
    geom_bar(data = . %>% filter( S == "b"), 
             aes(fill = groups), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_bar(data = . %>% filter( S == "a"),
            aes(group = groups),
             fill = "grey80", stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

You can adjust `fill = "grey80"` to get the exact colour you'd like.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!